# Limit of a conditional probability concerning a sequence of random bit-rewrites

Tags: probability, probability-theory, polynomials, random-variables, conditional-probability

Suppose a sequence of random bits $(X_1,X_2,...)$ is defined as follows, where $X_0=1$ and $p\in(0,1):$
$$X_i=\begin{cases}X_{i-1}&\text{ with probability }p,\\[1ex] 1-X_{i-1}&\text{ with probability }1-p. \end{cases}\\[2ex]$$
Thus each random bit is either a *direct copy* or an *inverted copy* of its predecessor.

> **Question**: How to prove the following? ... $$\text{For all }p\in(0,1),\ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}P(X_1=1\mid X_n=1)=p.\tag{1}$$

Plots suggest conjecture (1), with monotonic convergence when $p\ge 1/2$ and oscillatory convergence when $p<1/2$:

[image]

For each $n$, $\mathsf P(X_1=1\mid X_n=1)={\mathsf P(X_1=1,X_n=1)\over\mathsf P(X_n=1)}$ is a ratio of polynomials in $p$, e.g. as below (in lowest form) for a few cases:

```
n  P(X_1 = 1 | X_n = 1)
-- --------------------
1  1 
2  p^2/(2*p^2 - 2*p + 1)
3  (2*p^2 - 2*p + 1)/(4*p^2 - 6*p + 3)
4  (4*p^4 - 6*p^3 + 3*p^2)/(8*p^4 - 16*p^3 + 12*p^2 - 4*p + 1)
5  (8*p^4 - 16*p^3 + 12*p^2 - 4*p + 1)/(16*p^4 - 40*p^3 + 40*p^2 - 20*p + 5)
6  (16*p^6 - 40*p^5 + 40*p^4 - 20*p^3 + 5*p^2)/(32*p^6 - 96*p^5 + 120*p^4 - 80*p^3 + 30*p^2 - 6*p + 1)
7  (32*p^6 - 96*p^5 + 120*p^4 - 80*p^3 + 30*p^2 - 6*p + 1)/(64*p^6 - 224*p^5 + 336*p^4 - 280*p^3 + 140*p^2 - 42*p + 7)
8  (64*p^8 - 224*p^7 + 336*p^6 - 280*p^5 + 140*p^4 - 42*p^3 + 7*p^2)/(128*p^8 - 512*p^7 + 896*p^6 - 896*p^5 + 560*p^4 - 224*p^3 + 56*p^2 - 8*p + 1)
```

If $n$ is not too large, these ratios are readily obtained by representing the events $(X_1=1,X_n=1)$ and $(X_n=1)$ as length-$n$ pattern strings of form $1??...?1$ and $???...?1$, respectively. Each of these can then be converted to a list of all possible bitstrings matching the pattern, whose probabilities are simple products whose sum is to be taken. E.g., with $q=1-p$, $$\mathsf P(X_1=1\mid X_n=3)={\mathsf P(1?1)\over \mathsf P(??1)}={\mathsf P(101)+\mathsf P(111)\over \mathsf P(001)+\mathsf P(011)+\mathsf P(101)+\mathsf P(111)}={pqq+ppp\over qpq+qqp+pqq+ppp}={2p^2 - 2p + 1\over 4p^2 - 6p + 3}.$$

We note that, apparently, when the ratios are expressed in lowest form,
$$\text{numerator of $\mathsf P(X_1=1\mid X_n=1)$}=\begin{cases}\text{denominator of $\mathsf P(X_1=1\mid X_{n-1}=1)$}&\text{for odd }n>1\\[2ex] p^2\times\text{denominator of $\mathsf P(X_1=1\mid X_{n-1}=1)$}&\text{for even }n>1 \end{cases}
$$

but I don't know if this is useful. (The question seems so elementary, I feel like a proof ought to be likewise -- sorry if I'm just not seeing something obvious.)

Comment: This question occurred to me while working on a recently closed-and-deleted [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4304531/16397) (by New User @Jake) about successive people affirming or denying an "office rumor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. $\text{Bernoulli}(1-p)$. Let $X_i$ be the indicator for the event $\{Z_1 + \cdots + Z_i \text{ is even}\}$. Then the process $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ has the same distribution as what you have specified.

Then $$P(X_1=1, X_n=1) = P(Z_1=0, Z_2 + \cdots + Z_n \text{ is even}) = P(Z_1=0) P(Z_2 + \cdots + Z_n \text{ is even})\\ \approx p/2.$$
Similarly,
$$P(X_1=0, X_n=1) = P(Z_1=1, Z_2 + \cdots + Z_n \text{ is odd}) = P(Z_1=1) P(Z_2 + \cdots + Z_n \text{ is odd}) \approx (1-p)/2.$$

So, we have $P(X_1=1 \mid X_n=1) \approx \frac{p/2}{p/2 + (1-p)/2} = p$.

To make the "$\approx$" rigorous, you essentially have to argue that "the probability that a $\text{Binom}(n, 1-p)$ random variable is even tends to $1/2$ as $n \to \infty$"; I have hand-waved it away for the sake of giving you intuition.

Comment: Thanks much for this. I felt sure there was some such "algebraic" approach. Using indicators $[...]$, I'd noticed that with iid $B_i\sim\text{Ber}(p)$, we have $X_1=[B_1=1], X_i=[B_i=X_{i-1}]$; e.g., $X_3=[B_3=[B_2=[B_1=1]];$ but I failed to notice that this is the **same** as $X_n=[n-(B_1+...+B_n) \text{ is even}],$ so I missed the connection to the Binomial distribution! (I think it's interesting that using your $Z_i\sim\text{Ber($1-p$)}$ instead of $B_i\sim\text{Ber($p$)}$ simplifies quite a bit.)